# Create several columns using an agregative function and grouping in data.table

Tags: r, datatable, statistics, summary

I have a value column in a DT (actions) and I wish to create quantile of that value by a group.
But the function quantile (actions, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8) outputs 4 columns and I don't know how to assign them into variables. I thought about something like that -

`S_data_Long[, c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4") = .(quantile (actions, probs = c(0.20, 0.40, 0.60, 0.80))), by = "RT_int"]`

But it results in an error -

`*Error: unexpected '=' in "  S_data_Long[!is.na(format) & item_short == item_curr, c("q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q99") ="*`

I don't want to use `:=` because it will assign the new columns to the current table instead of creating a new one.

Comment: If you don't want to change `S_data_Long` why not create a `copy` of `S_data_Long` i.e `S_data_Long_copy <- copy(S_data_Long)` and use `:=` to assign new columns in `S_data_Long_copy` ?

Comment: It is a possibility, I can also create the columns one by one, but I think there needs to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: What you mean by elegant? If you don't want to use `:=` then why are you using `data.table`, you can convert the data to dataframe and use `<-`

Comment: Because it is an aggregate. I don't the quintiles for every observation, I want a summary table.